# IOS Objective-C moving multiple objects with just the UIKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

The problem I am facing is that I have absolutely no idea how to create multiple balls that move with their own speed, have their own location. That kind of thing. When I click the screen, a ball should start moving up. When I click again, another ball should start moving up. You get the idea. I've looked at several source codes and tutorials but I really don't understand how this is achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be doing this with SpriteKit ([see video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/))

But if you want to keep it really simple, your approach could be something like:

- Create a Ball class (object) (this could, if you want, contain the image of the ball)
- Initiate a new Ball object on every touch: `Ball *ball = [Ball alloc] init]];`
- Start animating the newly created `ball` (using basic animation for instance)

Comment: Hey Mikael, thanks for your suggestions. That's what i'm looking for. I'll go with the simple approach. I don't really have need of changing the speed of the ball at any given moment, just animating it is enough.